# Automatically setting scale on a graph based on max value (Python)

Tags: python, graph, scale

I want to automatically set the vertical scale on a line graph, based on the maximum value in a dataset. So far I came up with this method:

```
if 0 < max and max <= 250:
    ymax = 250
elif 250 < max and max <= 500:
    ymax = 500
elif 500 < max and max <= 750:
    ymax = 750
elif 750 < max and max <= 1000:
    ymax = 1000
```

Could anyone recommend a more concise approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

another not so intuitive implementation

```
def vScale(xmax):
    return ((xmax-1)/250+1)*250
```

and here is the result

```
[(x,vScale(x)) for x in xrange(0,1200,50)]
```

`[(0, 0), (50, 250), (100, 250), (150, 250), (200, 250), (250, 250), (300, 500), (350, 500), (400, 500), (450, 500), (500, 500), (550, 750), (600, 750), (650, 750), (700, 750), (750, 750), (800, 1000), (850, 1000), (900, 1000), (950, 1000), (1000, 1000), (1050, 1250), (1100, 1250), (1150, 1250)]`

And yet another implementation

```
limits=[0,250,500,750,1000]
ymax=limits[bisect.bisect_right(limits,xmax-1)]
```

Add one more to the bouquet

```
def vScale(xmax):
    return [250,500,750,1000][(xmax-1)/250]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please don't call a variable `max`, that's a builtin function.

```
if 0 < xmax <= 250:
    ymax = 250
elif xmax <= 500:
    ymax = 500
elif xmax <= 750:
    ymax = 750
elif xmax <= 1000:
    ymax = 1000
```

Note that Python allows comparisons of the form `x < y < z` with the meaning `x < y and y < z`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify it still more:

```
if mymax < 250:
    ymax = 250
elif mymax < 500:
    ymax = 500
elif mymax < 750:
    ymax = 750
else:
    ymax = 1000
```

and in a more generic way:

```
>>> mymax = 633
>>> limits = [250, 500, 750, 1000]
>>> for m in limits:
...     if mymax < m:
...         ymax = m
...         break
...         
>>> ymax
750
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is pretty concise:

```
min(th for th in (250, 500, 750, 1000) if val <= th)
```

where `val` is the variable you call `max` (I've renamed it to avoid shadowing the builtin).

The `(250, 500, 750, 1000)` can be replaced with any iterable (or even a generator).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a for loop:

```
for i in range(4):
    if 250*i < max <= 250*(i+1):
        max = 250*(i+1)
        break
```

(although agree with others that the variable probably shouldn't be called "max")

Answer (score 0):

See this answer: [how to determine a correct domain for a range of numbers for drawing a line-graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8605998/957595)